# Why Number and Symbol are frozen and cannot edit them?

Tags: puredata

Number and Symbol  are frozen and cannot edit them. I cannot also change width. Both actions are possible with Message, Object and Comment.

[image: Pure Data patch Untitled-1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is normal behavior.
Pd has two modes, in both modes your patch is being continuously computed. The patch in your screenshot is currently in **Edit mode** as you can see in the window title bar: `[edit]`.
In the menu "Edit" the last entry will let you switch Edit mode off (keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>). The other mode doesn't officially have a name, let's call it the "interactive mode" for now. The Edit mode is meant for patching: Placing and moving atoms around and connecting them to another. In "interactive mode" some atoms become GUI elements to change their values or send messages.

In **interactive mode**, the atoms behave this way:

- *Object:* Static.
- *Message:* Click to send content, outline of box will become thick for a moment.
- *Number:* Click and drag up to increment, down to decrement. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, click and drag to change the numbers after the decimal point. Doubleclick, type number and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd> to set to specific value and send it. <kbd>Ctrl.</kbd>+ click: Set to `0`.
- *Symbol:* Doubleclick, type symbol name and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>  to set to specific symbol and send it.
- *Comment:* Static.

In **edit mode**, the atoms behave this way:

- *Object:* Click to type content. Mouse over right edge: Click and drag to change box width.
- *Message:* Click to type content. Mouse over right edge: Click and drag to change box width.
- *Number:* Static.
- *Symbol:* Static.
- *Comment:* Click to type content. Mouse over right edge: Click and drag to change (column-) width.

Answer (score 0):

For people looking better explanation of differences in editing Numbers/Symbols and Messages/Objects/Comments I am adding answer of Seb Shader from Pure Data Facebook Group:

> As you learn pd it will become apparent: basically, number and symbol boxes are meant to be GUI elements where you can enter/change parameters. The contents of message boxes and object boxes aren't generally designed to change when the patch is run (although dynamic patching and the messages like "add2" etc. for message boxes are used. However these techniques are generally automated and not done by hand when the patch is used).